# How to run a .cab file on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-ce

We have an application which was developed for Windows Compact Edition.Its a .cab application.Can we run that application in windows 8?

I tried with DISM but It didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at this post.This approach uses windows package manger. http://app2pack.blogspot.com/2015/10/steps-to-install-cab-file-in-windows-7.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already tried that approach. But Windows package Manager is deprecated in Windows 8. I got a message saying Windows Package Manager is deprecated and shall try with DISM. But with DISM also I was not able to do.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: "Not able to read the cab file". This is the error I got when I executed the following command.  "dism /Online /Add-Package /PacakgePath:C:\Path to cab file".

Comment: This could be due to lack of permission or cab file is actually corrupted or something,have you tried in admin mode and cab file in a different OS/Machine?can you post content of DISM log file?

Comment: Which Visual Studio-Version did you use for creating your cab-file and which framework-version are you using?